# How to use ellipsis for zap global logger

Tags: go, go-zap

Hello I am trying to change sugar logger to global longer I checked possible fields which I can use but I couldn't something solve my problem

for example in some situations I use

```
                    zap.L().Debug("recv_cmd",
                        zap.String("user", c.GetString("user")),
                        zap.String("path", c.Request.URL.Path),
                    )
```

This is what I use in most of the cases but I have one different case which like this

```
    params := make([]interface{}, 0, 20)
    params = append(params,
        "status", c.Writer.Status(),
        "method", c.Request.Method
        "path", c.Request.URL.Path,
        "ip", c.ClientIP(),
    )
    if len(body) > 0 {
        params = append(params, "body", string(body))
    }
```

so in this case, I don't have a body in every request, so params obj doesn't have the same struck for each request

what I want is (this is just a simple demonstration I know stringer won't work)

```
    zap.L().Info("Info",
        zap.Stringer("request", params...),
    )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The definition of [Logger.Info](https://pkg.go.dev/go.uber.org/zap#Logger.Info) is:

```golang
func (log *Logger) Info(msg string, fields ...Field)
```

and the definition of [zap.Stringer](https://pkg.go.dev/go.uber.org/zap#Stringer) is:

```golang
func Stringer(key string, val fmt.Stringer) Field
```

So there are a number of issues with what you are attempting:

- You cannot pass `[]interface{}` to a function that accepts `fmt.Stringer` (because it does not implement the interface).
- `zap.Stringer` returns a single `Field` whereas you are really trying to log multiple fields.

What I think you are trying to accomplish is ([playground](https://go.dev/play/p/AEAHfKW9_zj)) (but I'm not really clear whether `params` is being created specifically for logging or for another reason):

```golang
var params []zap.Field
params = append(params,
    zap.String("status", c.Status),
    zap.String("method", c.Method),
    zap.String("path", c.URL.Path),
    zap.String("ip", c.ClientIP),
)
if len(body) > 0 {
    params = append(params, zap.String("body", string(body)))
}
zap.L().Info("Info", params...)
```

If that does not do what you are doing take a look at the variety of [encoders](https://pkg.go.dev/go.uber.org/zap#Field) that zap provides (e.g. [`Any`](https://pkg.go.dev/go.uber.org/zap#Any), [`Inline`](https://pkg.go.dev/go.uber.org/zap#Inline) etc).

Note: I have simplified your structure somewhat (because you did not include details). It is easier to answer questions like this if you include a [minimum reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (i.e. you should define structures used but only to the degree needed to illustrate the issue).